# Using multiple displays on my DisplayPort laptop

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have a laptop (HP EliteBook) with a single DisplayPort on the side. I know for sure that with a HP docker station one can use two monitors with this laptop.

Anyway the docker station is somewhat expensive and this is an office laptop so I don't want to buy one for a laptop that isn't even mine.

When working from home I have two monitors: a recent HDMI one and an older DVI (I think DVI-I) one.

Is there any way I can connect both of them (even if they're different brands) to my laptop DisplayPort to use them in an extend-monitor configuration (so that they will appear as different parts of the desktop)?

Comment: No. It will work if you have two display port monitors. DP (v1.2 or higher with MST) allows you do daisy chain. Doing a laptop ---> monitor 1 <----> Monitor 2.  But as far as I know you cannot get that to work unless the middle monitor is DP (and has an in and out plug). And even then not sure if you can get the second chained screen working as non DO monitor.

Comment: I guess I will have to stick with the more recent monitor then. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Answer written Wait a few days before accepting, a better answer may come along.  PS: I use an HP elitebook for work and I did buy a docking station with 3x monitor out for about 60 EUR in NL. So that might still be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using multiple displays on my DisplayPort laptop

Using multiple display using DP is not a problem. [Displayport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) 1.3 or higher support MST, allowing you to chain multiple monitors; assuming that:

1. You have a modern enough graphics card (DP 1.3 or higher. Should be all modern ones, but not on some old generations).
2. Your monitors supports it (ditto. Old ones might not. Or cheap ones. I have a modern 4K DP screen in front of me but rather than 1 or 2 DP in and 1 out it only has 1 input).
3. At least on of your monitors has an DP in and a DP out port.

Now here are three catches:

- I am not sure if this will work with only one proper laptop, one proper monitor and the second (or rather, last, screen) not DP.
- Bandwitdth is shared across the laptops output port. So while one DP port might feed one 8k screen or two 4k screens, or four 2k screens (2540x1600).